# build-simple-cdd Invalid checksum at tmp/mirror/README

Tags: shell, debian

My working machine is Linux Debian Buster (10.0).
I am trying to create a Simple CDD iso from root account:

Cmdline used:

```
build-simple-cdd --debug --dist buster --force-root
```

Response:

```
2019-07-07 11:24:52,978 DEBUG Reading configuration...
gpg: directory '/root/.gnupg' created
gpg: /root/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
2019-07-07 11:24:53,042 DEBUG Checking configuration...
2019-07-07 11:24:53,273 DEBUG Creating build environment in /root...
2019-07-07 11:24:53,378 DEBUG Building local Debian mirror for debian-cd...
2019-07-07 11:24:53,379 DEBUG downloading: /root/tmp/mirror/extrafiles
2019-07-07 11:24:53,867 DEBUG verify gpg signature running command gpg --batch --no-default-keyring --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg --verify /root/tmp/mirror/extrafiles
2019-07-07 11:24:53,899 DEBUG verify gpg signature stderr: gpg: Signature made Sat 06 Jul 2019 04:34:24 AM CEST
2019-07-07 11:24:53,900 DEBUG verify gpg signature stderr: gpg:                using RSA key 126C0D24BD8A2942CC7DF8AC7638D0442B90D010
2019-07-07 11:24:53,911 DEBUG verify gpg signature stderr: gpg: Good signature from "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (8/jessie) <ftpmaster@debian.org>" [unknown]
2019-07-07 11:24:53,915 DEBUG verify gpg signature stderr: gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
2019-07-07 11:24:53,915 DEBUG verify gpg signature stderr: gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
2019-07-07 11:24:53,916 DEBUG verify gpg signature stderr: Primary key fingerprint: 126C 0D24 BD8A 2942 CC7D  F8AC 7638 D044 2B90 D010
2019-07-07 11:24:53,917 DEBUG verify gpg signature retval: 0
2019-07-07 11:24:53,994 DEBUG downloading: /root/tmp/mirror/README
2019-07-07 11:24:54,462 ERROR Invalid checksum for /root/tmp/mirror/README: expected 463536fa7b9fd3800f1957f4fc5690ca8739e87efda85d81ae3b46306469da03, got 4e96e82b362f9b4d7a0670a3ec6b053d451db98a1df55471671b70170db7bc04
```

Any clues ???
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I'm nearly certain this has to do with the update to 10.0 yesterday.  I was able to get past this particular error by editing the readme with the details as if it were 9.9 (with 8.11 going to old and looking up the details for 7.11 as oldold).  However, I then got another checksum error for a different file.

I'm just going to wait until people more capable than me update cdd.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right, now simple-cdd works fine again.
Regards